# Do we need a salesforce.com tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I see five questions tagged with "salesforce.com." Since this site is dedicated to Salesforce, is it really necessary?  I would suggest that SFDC just be the default and that perhaps we only tag the ancillary SFDC offerings (if they are even appropriate for this site.)

Do we need or want a salesforce.com tag?

Comment: +1 for that - need to delete this tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've deleted this tag, and blacklisted it in the intrinsic fashion of [salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salesforce) - questions with this tag on other sites may be migrated freely here, provided they have some other relevant tag.

(Note that it's already a synonym of [salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salesforce) on Stack Overflow, so this seems pretty clear-cut)