# What does the 'salesforce-instance' tag mean?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've seen a few [questions tagged salesforce-instance](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salesforce-instance). I can't think that this tag is necessary or desirable - it seems to be as redundant as [salesforce.com](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69/do-we-need-a-salesforce-com-tag).

Any thoughts before I go deleting tags with extreme prejudice?

Answer (score 6):

Sure looks useless to me. None of the questions tagged with it have anything instance/pod specific, so I agree with deleting it.

Comment: Thanks - I'll wait a few hours to allow a respectable quorum, then go in with the machete...

Comment: I vote to delete it.

Comment: I'm now officially considering this a quorum and just went through and removed it from all posts. Is it possible for a moderator to actually delete and blacklist it?

Comment: Interested to know if a moderator can blacklist a tag.